# The right file name for an enum?

Tags: vb.net, enums, naming-conventions

I have a DataType (text, numeric, date, boolean, money) enum and I need to put that in a file. How should I call the file and where in my DataAccessLayer.Generic namespace should I put the file into? Right now the file is called enum.vb and is in the DataAccessLayer.Generic.DataTypes namespace. The Result is DataAccessLayer.Generic.DataTypes.DataType, but it is misleading because the file is called enum.vb

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the file `DataType.vb` since that is the name of the type within the file.

Without knowing more about your application's architecture it would be difficult to give namespace advice but this should be fine:

```
DataAccessLayer.Generic.DataTypes.DataType
```

Especially if the `DataAccessLayer.Generic.DataTypes` namespace contains other types and the enumeration in question belongs with them.

Comment: Yep, some of my files have few characters (delegate declarations for example), but by following these names you sure can find things. :)

Comment: Yes, DataTypes contains TextDataType, NumericDataType, BooleanDataType, DateDataType... Each on implements a IDataTypeDecorator that has a ReadOnly Property DataType as DataType

Answer (score 0):

I have put Enums into a file which I call 'Common', meaning it is shared among the entire namespace.  I know that breaks 1 item per file rule, to me Enums are an exception to that rule.

Comment: All of the types are common to the namespace. By that rule, you could get away with 1 file per namespace.

Comment: Just Enums.  So I have a namespace of Foo.Bar.Data in the data folder there would be a commmon file that contains the Enums for everything in Foo.Bar.Data.  An object called GenericAccessObj has its own file.